# Projections of the Product Topology

Tags: general-topology, projection

I've recently been studying product topologies from *Schaum's General Topology* and it appears that this is where topology begins to get fairly abstract (i.e. working in several dimensions). In the Product Topology chapter, the author defines

> A **projection** is a function $\pi_{j_0}: X \to X_{j_0}$ where $X=\prod X_i$ is the product set and $X_{j_0}$ is a coordinate space. The function is given by $\pi_{j_0}(\langle a_i: i \in I\rangle)= a_{j_0}$

The author also goes on to say that the **product topology** is the topology generated by these projections.

I'd like to pose two questions:

1. Is it safe to say that a projection is merely a function that picks the $k^{th}$ element from an $n$-dimensional point in a product space and returns the value from $X_k$? e.g. let $\hat{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\hat{x}= (4,5,6),$ then $\pi_2(\hat{x}) = 5$. Would that be sensible?
2. I'm having trouble understanding how the projections generate a topology. By "generate," surely we mean "take arbitrary unions of," but I am failing to see how $\displaystyle\bigcup \pi_i(\hat{x})$ is a base for  $\prod X_i$.

Comment: Regarding your first question: yes, that is indeed the definition of a projection in this sense. It's merely a map that picks a specific value from an arbitrary tuple, just as in your example.

Comment: That's great because the book I'm reading defines it so obscurely - and that's probably because they define Cartesian products very abstractly. In Schaum's, instead of just calling Cartesian products the set of all ordered pairs from $n$ spaces, they say a Cartesian product is the set of all functions from an index set $f: I \to \bigcup X_i$ such that $f(i)=x_i \in X_i$. So you could understand why projections suddenly become very obscure.

Comment: Yes, often times it seems overly complicated. Of course they're simply being as rigorous as possible, which is good, but in this case I agree that it's better to think of a projection in the way you described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1.

Sure, that's fine. Your use of "$n$-dimensional" suggests you're only thinking of products of finitely many spaces, which will hold you back and/or lead to confusion when you move on to considering products of infinitely many spaces.

## 2.

> By "generate," surely we mean "take arbitrary unions of,"

Unfortunately, there are lots of meanings of "generate" that you need to use context to distinguish. In this case, "arbitrary unions of" is not the right meaning.

Here, since we have functions rather than open sets, the intended meaning is related to making the projection functions continuous. By thinking through what interpretation might be reasonable (since the discrete topology would easily make the projections continuous), the intended meaning is actually that:

> The product topology is the coarsest topology where all the projection functions are continuous. (i.e. the intersection of all topologies that make the projections continuous)

Comment: I have encountered the fact that the product topology is the coarsest topology in which all projections are continuous, but in order to have continuity, don't we need to know how we're defining our open sets, i.e. a function is continuous iff the preimage of every open set is open. If we're not taking unions with the projections, what exactly are the projections doing?

Comment: @SunRoad2 I just edited in a way to think about "coarsest" which may help: the open sets are whichever sets are open in *all* topologies that keep the projections continuous.

Comment: Oh I see now, that certainly helps!